# Using Ptr<IplImage> in OpenCv causes memory exception

Tags: opencv, out-of-memory

```
void hello(Mat original)
{
  Mat a=original.clone();
  Ptr<IplImage> b = &a.operator IplImage();
  return;
}
```

This function will cause a memory exception. Beause I have to use an old funciton which parameter is IplImage*, I transform the Mat into Ptr and cause memory exception. The above function is just a simplified version.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the right way to use old version OpenCv function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator-iplimage)

> The operator creates the IplImage header for the matrix without copying the underlying data. **You should make sure than the original matrix is not deallocated while the IplImage header is used.**

You can pass the reference of the returned header to a function that accepts an `IplImage*`, like`void foo(IplImage* img)` in the code below):

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

void foo(IplImage* img)
{
    // Set to blue
    cvSet(img, Scalar(255,0,0));
}

int main()
{
    // Small green image
    Mat3b img(10, 10, Vec3b(0, 255, 0));

    {
        // Doesn't modify original image
        Mat mat = img.clone();
        IplImage ipl = mat;
        foo(&ipl);

        // ipl and mat are blue now
        // img is still green
    }

    {
        // Modify original image
        IplImage ipl = img;
        foo(&ipl);

        // ipl and img are blue now
    }

    // img is blue

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer make me understand the reason of my function exception.

Answer (score 0):

`Ptr<T>` is a template class thats performs automatic destruction of the wrapped object pointer (see the [official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#ptr) for more information about it).

In your code snippet, both `a` and `b` are local variables inside the function `hello`, so they will be destroyed when this function returns and in the reverse order of construction, so `a` will be destroyed after the destruction of `b`.

The memory exception could occur because both variables (`a` and `b`) refer to the same memory area: in fact, the function [`Mat::operator IplImage`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator-iplimage) **does not copy the underlying data** of the `Mat` object, but creates the `IplImage` header for these matrix data.

So when the `Mat` destructor will try to destroy the object `a`, the portion of memory dedicated to the underlying data will already have been deallocated by `b`.